# How importing from a script works differently than importing from a module?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a structure of files and folders like this:

```
package1/
  p1.py
  package2/
    p2.py
```

Contents of `package1/p1.py`:

```
def p1fun():
    print("p1fun")
```

Contents of `package1/package2/p2.py`:

```
import package1.p1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  package1.p1.p1fun()
```

Now, when I do `python -m package1.package2.p2`, I get the correct result = `p1fun`. When I do `python package1/package2/p2.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/marcin/projects/test/package1/package2/p2.py", line 1, in <module>
import package1.p1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'
```

How the import mechanism differs in these two scenarios? How to make the "script" scenario import properly?

Comment: When you run a script its folder is added to the PYTHONPATH, if you use `-m` the current folder is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add the directory containing package1 to `sys.path`. A simple way is to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to `.`:

```
export PYTHONPATH='.'   # on Linux or other Unix-like

set PYTHONPATH=.        # on Windows
```

Underlying cause:

As explained by @KlausD. , python automatically adds the path of the script passed on the command line, or the current path when you start a module with `python -m`. A simple way to *see* it is to print `sys.path` close to the beginning of `p2.py`:

```
import package1.p1

import sys

print(sys.path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  package1.p1.p1fun()
```

For `python -m package1.package2.p2` you can see that the first element of the list is the current folder, for `python package1/package2/p2.py` you will instead have: `/path/to/current/package1/package2`